# Reading Large JSON file in R

Tags: json, r, large-files, yelp

I want to read or convert to CSV file a large JSON file (2Gb) in R. I almost tried everything in this blog and others and i couldn't succeed till now.

The JSON file is related to Yelp Round 7 Challenge and you can download through the following link.
https://www.yelp.co.uk/dataset_challenge

I used the normal rjson library and i got the following error:

```
> library(rjson)
> df <- fromJSON(file = "yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset.json")
Error in fromJSON(file = "yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset.json") : unexpected character 'D'`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. _"I almost tried everything"_ - feel free to add it (and therefore some value) to your post.

Answer (score 0):

What are the errors you are having? For example, with [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045#miserables.json) JSON data:

To load the initial json file with the **rjson** library:

```
df <- fromJSON(file = "path/to/miserables.json")
```

You will need to do some work to get it out though:

```
names <- unlist(lapply(df$nodes, function(x){x$name}))
groups <- unlist(lapply(df$nodes, function(x){x$group}))

final.df <- data.frame(names,groups)
```

Comment: Forst,   unexpected character 'D' is kind of error i got

Comment: > library(rjson)  
    > df <- fromJSON(file = "yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset.json")  
    Error in fromJSON(file = "yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset.json") : 
  unexpected character 'D'}

Comment: Have you inspected the file for that unexpected character?

Comment: how could i do that, i tried some online tools but the file is too big 2Gb and i couldnt find tool that could do it

Comment: I got the same error when loading the dataset, but found an error in the first line of the file (by the looks of things it is not a pure JSON file, but it is trying to read a title at the very start of the file which starts with D). I used the `readLines` function to find this. 

Try opening the file in an editor that can handle large files and editing these bits out.